# How to recover from Time Machine "error creating the backup folder"

Tags: time-machine, backup, error

Today TimeMachine crashed: it isn't making backups... when I try to start a newbackup, I get this error:

**Time Machine could not complete the backup "Drive Name".
Could not complete the backup. There was an error creating the backup folder.**

I had this problem before and the "solution" was formatting the drive but this time I have a lot of backups and I want to know if there is any other way without having to format my drive.

[image: This message appear in my Mac, the tradition is in bold]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before as well & I need to admit, I just formatted the drive - which is probably the easiest way. If you don't really need any of the old backups, maybe consider this again.

Alternatively you could try to run the Disk Utility App and try to repair your Backup Drive!

Comment: Good news... First I erased the last backup and after I use disk utility and time machine does backups normally again